# RegEx: match any non-word and non-digit character except

Tags: java, regex

To match any non-word and non-digit character (special characters) I use this: `[\\W\\D]`. What should I add if I want to also ignore some concrete characters? Let's say, underscore.

Comment: Do you mean any non-word *or* non-digit character? Because that's what `[\W\D]` matches.

Comment: @arshajii I'm assuming he's escaping the backslashes in a string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, you must know that `\W` is equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`. So, you can change your current regex to:

```
[\\W]
```

This will automatically take care of `\D`.

Now, if you want to ignore some other character, say `&` (underscore is already exluded in `\W`), you can use negated character class:

```
[^\\w&]
```

Comment: [\\W] does not match numbers